# D3.js data update "remembers" old data

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I want to update a bar chart, but it "remembers" the length of the data i initialized it with.
Here is what I think I do:

- creating the chart and draw it for the first time with an array of 5 objects - rendering this works fine
- updating the chart with a subsample of the original data (only 4 objects now)
- the update works, but it does not render the bars over each other, but leaves a gap where the removed object was before.

I would like the update to cause the bar chart to display only the remaining objects in the array without the gap. What am I doing wrong?

You can find the code here: http://tributary.io/inlet/8919193 to play with it. Or in plain form here:

```
  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var BarChart = function BarChart( chart_attributes ){
    // hide variables within function scope
    var chart = {},
        data;

    // data setter and getter
    chart.data = function( new_data ){
      if( new_data ){ data = new_data; }
      return data; 
    };

    // update data and redraw chart
    chart.update = function( new_data ){
      // update data
      if( !new_data ){ console.log("chart.update() - no data set!"); }
      else{ chart.data( new_data ); }   

      // redraw
      var bar_attr = chart_attributes.bars;
      var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data( chart.data(), function(d){ return d.NAME } );

      var g = groups.enter().append("g")
         .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(100," + ((i * bar_attr.height)+100) + ")"; });

      var bars = g.append("rect")
        .attr("x", bar_attr.x)
        .attr("height", bar_attr.height-1).transition()
      .attr("width", function(d,i){return d.INTENSITY*10} );

      g.append("text")
        .attr("y", bar_attr.height-2 )
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("font-size", bar_attr.height )
        .text( bar_attr.label);

      groups.exit().remove();

    };


    return chart;
  };


  var data = [ 
    { "INTENSITY": 9,  "NAME": "label 1"},
    { "INTENSITY": 10, "NAME": "label 2"},
    { "INTENSITY": 10, "NAME": "label 3"},
    { "INTENSITY": 13, "NAME": "label 4"},
    { "INTENSITY": 21, "NAME": "label 5"}
  ];

  var margin_top = 50,
      margin_left = 70,
      bar_height = 20;

  var bar_attributes = {
    "x": margin_left,
    "y": function(d,i){ return (i*bar_height)+margin_top;},
    "height": bar_height,
    "width": function(d,i){ return d.INTENSITY*10},
    "label": function(d,i){ return d.NAME }
  };

  var attr = {"bars": bar_attributes };

  var chart = new BarChart( attr );

  chart.update(data);
  data.splice(1,1)
  chart.update(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not updating the positions of the bars for updated data. The code that sets the position of the `g` elements is only run on new data:

```
var g = groups.enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(100," + ((i * bar_attr.height)+100) + ")"; });
```

Replacing this with

```
var g = groups.enter().append("g");
groups.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(100," + ((i * bar_attr.height)+100) + ")"; });
```

fixes the problem -- the position is set for the all new and existing `g` elements now. Complete example [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/8921290).